# Read/write Firebase database with auth - is auth passed automtically?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

When I've the following rules in my Firebase DB:

```
  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

It means that only signed in users can read and write to my DB.
Suppose the user is authenticated and I've these variables:

```
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

and that `mFirebaseUser != null`

My question is what's the proper way to read this data for a signed in user?
When I read the data this way, does it somehow send the to the Database that `mFirebaseUser != null`?

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    SomeDataObj cur = d.getValue(SomeDataObj.class);
                    // Do work with SomeDataObj
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user accessing the database through the SDK is signed in, the `auth` variable in your security rules is automatically populated.

So your current rules allow the user to read and write all data if they're signed in.

If a user isn't signed in and tries to read/write the data, the operation is rejected by the database. You'll want to implement the `onCancelled(...)` callback to handle this situation (and make sure it doesn't get hidden):

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
}
```